# How to parse DateTime in format yyyyMMddHHmmss to OffsetDateTime using DateFormatter

Tags: java, datetimeformatter, offsetdatetime

I have an API for JSON parsing which requires a DateTimeFormatter instance in order to parse date time strings to OffsetDateTime. However I always get an exception **Unable to obtain ZoneOffset from TemporalAccessor: {},ISO resolved to 2021-08-17T13:26:49 of type java.time.format.Parsed**
The API uses OffsetDateTime.parse(String, DateFormatter).

```
// DateTimeFormatter instance to be provided to the API
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
// this is how the API uses the DateTimeFormatter instance
OffsetDateTime dateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse("20210817132649", formatter);
```

How do I have to create the DateTimeFormatter in order to deliver a ZoneOffset, so that the API is able to parse the DateTime correctly. The ZoneOffset may be UTC.

Comment: Yes, I tried:  

Unable to obtain OffsetDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {InstantSeconds=1629206809},ISO,Z resolved to 2021-08-17T13:26:49

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the string you passed in does not contain zone information, while an `OffsetDateTime` requires zone information.

So you'll have to set a value for it.

You could use the `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` class, which then can be instructed to use some default value if a field is missing from the parsed information:

```java
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.OFFSET_SECONDS, 0)
    .appendPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmss")
    .toFormatter(Locale.ROOT);
```

You could also directly set an implied zone to the `DateTimeFormatter`:

```java
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmss").withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

Comment: The DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmss").withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC); doesn't work. However with the DateTimeFormatterBuilder is was able to get the String parsed correctly

Answer (score 4):

#### Update

I understood from you that you are using the API as follows:

```
apiClient.getJSON().setOffsetDateTimeFormat(DateTimeFormatter);
```

and you do not have a parameter to pass timezone information. In this case, you can use `DateTimeFormatter#withZone` as shown below:

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuuMMddHHmmss", Locale.ENGLISH)
                                        .withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);

        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse("20210817132649", formatter);

        System.out.println(odt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-08-17T13:26:49Z
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/nBdGwE)

i.e. now, your call will be:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuuMMddHHmmss", Locale.ENGLISH)
                                .withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);

apiClient.getJSON().setOffsetDateTimeFormat(formatter);
```

#### Original answer

Your date-time string does not have a timezone offset. Parse it into a `LocalDateTime` and then apply the offset to it.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuuMMddHHmmss", Locale.ENGLISH);
        
        OffsetDateTime odt = LocalDateTime.parse("20210817132649", formatter)
                                .atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC);
        
        System.out.println(odt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-08-17T13:26:49Z
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/8xVfSO)

The `Z` in the output is the [timezone designator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators) for zero-timezone offset. It stands for Zulu and specifies the `Etc/UTC` timezone (which has the timezone offset of `+00:00` hours). You can specify a different timezone offset (e.g. `ZoneOffset.of("+05:30")`) as per your requirement.

#### In case you have `ZoneId` available

If you have `ZoneId` available, you should parse the given date-time string into a `LocalDateTime` and then apply the `ZoneId` to it to get a `ZonedDateTime` from which you can always obtain an `OffsetDateTime`. The best thing about a `ZonedDateTime` is that it has been designed to adjust the timezone offset automatically whereas an `OffsetDateTime` is used to represent a fixed timezone offset.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuuMMddHHmmss", Locale.ENGLISH);

        ZonedDateTime zdt = LocalDateTime.parse("20210817132649", formatter)
                                .atZone(ZoneId.of("Etc/UTC"));

        OffsetDateTime odt = zdt.toOffsetDateTime();

        System.out.println(odt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-08-17T13:26:49Z
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/gBOL9q)

You can specify a different `ZoneId`(e.g. `ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata")`) as per your requirement.

Learn more about the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table). Note that Android 8.0 Oreo already provides [support for `java.time`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/package-summary).</sup>

Comment: I know that the date-time string has no time-zone. But I can only provide a DateTimeFormatter to the API. Thus, I am not able to do the .atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC).

Comment: @Stefan - Is it a Spring application?

Comment: No, I use a ApiClient generated via swagger, and can pass the DateFormatter this way: apiClient.getJSON().setOffsetDateTimeFormat(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmss"));

Comment: @Stefan - Please check if there is a way to pass the timezone e.g. `timezone="UTC"`

Comment: There is no property for timezone, offset or zoneId.

Comment: @Stefan - I have posted an update which should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Better use a `ZonedDateTime` - the difference being the Day Saving Time, and countries on with the same zone offset. Maybe using the default `ZoneId`.